# How to get the area for a bounding box for each point in a plannar point pattern (ppp) data using Spatstat in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, spatstat

I have a point pattern object (ppp) i.e. dataset comprising the geographic coordinates of certain positions. For example:

```
> data(bei)
> df1<-as.data.frame(bei)
> View(df1)
> head(df1)
      x     y
1  11.7 151.1
2 998.9 430.5
3 980.1 433.5
4 986.5 425.8
5 944.1 415.1
6 940.5 410.4
```

Now, I would like to fit a small bounding box of some dimension over each points in the ppp object and compute its area. How to do this using spatstat?

Or should I pixellate the ppp object? In that case, how to get the pixel area?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `spatstat`, but perhaps all you want is to find a smallest rectangle containing all the points given by, e.g., `head(df1)` and its area? I'm asking because it seems like you question could be answered without knowing about `spatstat`, in which case you are much more likely to get a quick answer.

Comment: Well I don't want a rectangle to contain all the points, that can be done easily by creating a window. I want to create rectangle or boxes for each points. How to do this in R (even without using spatstat)?

Comment: https://www.neonscience.org/field-data-polygons-centroids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `spatstat` package, the function `boundingbox` computes the smallest rectangle that contains the spatial objects specified. In your example, you could type `boundingbox(bei)` to get the smallest rectangle containing all the data points in the point pattern dataset `bei`. The area is computed using `area(boundingbox(bei))`. If instead of a point pattern dataset you just had a data frame of coordinates, e.g. `df <- as.data.frame(bei)`, then similarly `boundingbox(df)` and `area(boundingbox(df))` give you the same information.

To search for information about `spatstat` you can type `help(spatstat)` for an overview of the available commands, or use `help.search` to search for keywords. Or visit [the spatstat.org website](http://www.spatstat.org).